# Is there a way to ignore form response?

Tags: html, forms

Is there a way to specify a form either through type or action url to not open the response? In other words I would like to send the info to the server, but not do anything on the client. I know I can use ajax and ignore the response, but I would like to avoid adding all the js to my code if possible.

Edit: I didn't mean to limit myself to the html form. In my case server side solutions were also acceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have the server return HTTP 204 (No Content) after the form submission. According to [the HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> 10.2.5 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request
>   but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return
>   updated metainformation. The response
>   MAY include new or updated
>   metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present
>   SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it
>   SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to
>   be sent. This response is primarily
>   intended to allow input for actions to
>   take place without causing a change to
>   the user agent's active document view,
>   although any new or updated
>   metainformation SHOULD be applied to
>   the document currently in the user
>   agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a
>   message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line
>   after the header fields.

This sounds like exactly what you want.

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
<iframe id="invisible" ...

<form target="invisible" ...
```

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted, this is a good idea, easy to implement, and works cross-browser.

Comment: This actually answers the question posed. If the question is, "Is there a way to ignore form response" the answer is not to change the response but to find a way to, you know, ignore the response. This technique just saved our bacon.

Answer (score 2):

I found that name attribute should be specified as well (I tested in IE11). E.g:

```
<iframe id="invisible" name="invisible" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form method="post" target="invisible" action="url.com/whatever?x=y" id="fileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: From my testing on Firefox on Windows, using `name` was necessary but `id` was not; do you know when each is needed? Perhaps this varies by browser and including both is safest.

Answer (score 0):

With ASP.NET you could have a page that processes the form post and simply end the response right away, this will leave the user at the same page.

However, no response to the user at all is not the best user experience.....

Comment: The user experience is actually the reason for the question. Currently a file is returned, but in this case it is empty and we don't want the browser to prompt with "open/save".