# Creating a view function without returning a response in Flask

Tags: jquery, python, sqlite, redis, flask

I'm rather new to web programming and Flask, and I've recently run into a problem with a website I am trying to create. I currently have a jquery procedure which sends a post request to a view function in Flask. This function simply increments a value in my database, and it's not really necessary for me to return a response after incrementing this value. However, as far as I've seen, view functions in Flask are required to return a Response object. I could of course trivially return some sort of json "was-updated" response, but it's really not important to my application. Does anyone know if the proper way to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: all requests have responses, it would be fine to return some sort of "trivial" response, would a `204` response be of help to you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3283126/594589, it includes a response with no body

Comment: @dm03514 turn your comment into an answer to this question. That is the right answer.

Comment: I concur, a 204 response will work great and Flask will actually strip any body you *do* try to send.

Answer (score 12):

It's quite simple, just return an empty string with 204 status code:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    # ...
    return '', 204
```